# Array for tableview returning 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

My app is a fake messaging app for kids. They “send a message”, and that segues to a message sent screen. When the message sent screen shows, it triggers a timer that delays a reply being created and added to an array, which will then be used to populate the “inbox” table. Using nslog, the timer runs, the method runs, the array is populated. But when I nslog the number of rows (being the result to array.count) it is logging 0. I’ve spent the afternoon trying to get the code working but I’m obviously missing something. I’ve even tried moving the “logic code” for creating the array to its own file to separate that and the table methods but it achieves the same result. 
The problem is that repliesArrayForTable in inbox table.m is returning null. But it nslogs the name as it should in inbox repliesMethod, and even if I create an instance of inbox in inboxTable and set it that way via view did load and repliesArrayForTable = inboxInstance.allReplies it still returns null.

```
@implementation inbox


@synthesize allReplies, childsName;

-(void)timerForOtherMethods {

        NSLog(@"populate array timer");
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:6 target:self selector:@selector(repliesMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    NSLog(@" add timer");
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}

-(NSMutableArray *)repliesMethod {

NSMutableArray *replies = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    [replies addObject:childsName]; // childsName set in messageSent
    NSLog(@" replies array includes: %@", replies); //logs name

    InboxTable *inboxTable = [[InboxTable alloc]init];
    inboxTable.repliesArrayForTable = replies; //logs as should

    return allReplies = replies;

}


@implementation InboxTable

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell Identifier";

@synthesize repliesArrayForTable;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"replies in array: %lu", (unsigned long)repliesArrayForTable.count);   // logs 0?
    return [repliesArrayForTable count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"From Sorting Office";

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: For questions like this, when `[array count] == 0` it normally means `array == nil`.  Ensure you are allocating it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
inboxTable.repliesArrayForTable = [replies mutableCopy]; //logs as should

return allReplies = [replies mutableCopy];
```

If that doesn't do the trick then *move* your **inboxTable** instance *outside* your **repliesMethod**.